# How to record RAM, CPU usage along with timestamp over an interval of x seconds? (AIX)

Tags: shell-script, aix

I need a script that logs RAM, CPU and Hard Disk usages on a time interval that can be specified. Timestamps should also be included in the logs.

Thereafter, I would need those logs exported to a .txt or a .csv file. It's for an AIX system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check for [`sa1`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/s_commands/sa1.html), `sa2`, [`sar`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/s_commands/sar.html) command. In man pages you will find how to run them in cron and how to extract the history records.